# Prometheus endpoint organization and manage

Tags: python, nginx, tornado, uwsgi, prometheus

My task is set up monitoring by using Prometheus. The whole idea is next: each time Prometheus make scrape from end-point (i.e makes GET request), on the web-server (now it's just [Tornado](https://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/)) starts appropriate handler (Python script), that do job and return metrics, which Prometheus collects.

Everything seems to be ok, but problem is that i use Tornado because of it asynchrony, and it cause problems(bugs, hard to handle exceptions and etc.), plus there is not much libraries, that work well with asyncio, so more often my hanlders don't work asynchronously, they just run code in threads.

So, what i want. I want to set up my web server to manage Prometheus requests not asynchronously, but using something like multiprocessing. I imagine every request from Prometheus like separate connection from user, and i want to process it aside from anothers connections(ideally - in separate interpreter process). I assume that this can be achieved by using a bunch of webserver(nginx), Python application server (uWSGI) and web framework (Flask, or another). How it looks like:

1. Prometheus makes GET request, say
   http://localhost/something_i_watch/metrics
2. nginx route it to appropriate endpoint
3. application server and web framework does job and returns metrics

Advantage: each request processed separately (it separate Python interpreter process), we have many possibilities for scaling, fast queries don't wait for slow, Python code is synchronous.

Is it good idea for me, or it can be better? Maybe i missing something? Sorry for mess, if he is there and thanks for yor suggestions.